# OneSignal rest API not working for Android

Tags: android, api, push-notification, nativescript, onesignal

I'm using OneSignal rest API to send notification from my server to specific devices. It works for all iOS devices but not with Android.

Am I missing some Android specific configuration here ?

```js
axios.post('https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications', {
    app_id: 'xxx',
    headings: { en: title },
    contents: { en: content },
    include_external_user_ids: [userIds],
    channel_for_external_user_ids: 'push',
    ios_badgeType: 'Increase',
    ios_badgeCount: 1,
}, { headers: { Authorization: `Basic xxx` } });
```

Note that when I send a notification from the dashboard it works on both iOS & Android devices.

Comment: What do you submit under `contents` key? Is it some custom data?

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu under `contents` its for example : `{ en: 'Text STRING message' }`

Comment: Have you tried to debug receiving notification data in `public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` on the Android side when your application is in the foreground? The case might be that you have some data passed with a notification when you using this post route. If so, showing notifications on Android device must be done solely by you from receiving, to parsing, creating notification itself and showing.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu yes I've tried. I receive something on iOS but nothing on Android... I guess there is an extra key the Android needs to be filled that I've missed.